# Why does Cocos2d-x not show the sprite the first time?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

What is the problem? It does not show the sprite the first time.

```
playerSprite = Sprite::create("ip.png");
playerSprite->setPosition(Vec2(visibleSize.width/2,visibleSize.height));
    //this->addChild(playerSprite,1);
    auto body = PhysicsBody::createCircle
        (playerSprite->getContentSize().width / 2.5);
    body->setContactTestBitmask(true);
    body->setDynamic(true);
    playerSprite->setPhysicsBody(body);
    this->addChild(playerSprite,0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Using Another Z-Order of your Sprite. this->addChild(playerSprite,**TRY_WITH_SOME_LARGE_VALUE**);`

AND see if the result are Same.

Answer (score 0):

Since you questions is not much defined, answer might be incorrect.

First of all, make sure that image is placed correctly and there is no typos in image name.

`playerSprite` `position` is in the middle of the top. to center it:

```
->setPosition(Point(visibleSize.widht * 0.5, visibleSize.height * 0.5));
```

If this == `Scene` you can do it like this.

```
->setPosition(Point(this->getContentSize().width * 0.5, this->getContentSize().height * 0.5));
```

Also when adding `Sprite` make sure there is no other `Sprite` above by setting `zOrder` to a bigger number

```
this->addChild(playerSprite, 100);
```